# Node/Express BodyParser not returning data from input fields or returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have a basic express set up. I'm trying to do something which on tutorials seems pretty simple but is not working at all for me. I'm attempting to capture the data entered by a user in two inputs, a text input and a dropdown input.

My app.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var pug = require('pug');

// initialize express
var app = express();

// set up port
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

// setting up bodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

// setting up views
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// initial homepage get
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var input = req.body.userInput;
    var quantity = req.body.quantity;

    console.log("input is: " + input);
    console.log("quantity is: " + quantity);
});

// listening on port
app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
});
```

My pug file form looks like this:

```
.card
   .card-body
     form(action='/', method="POST")
       .form-row
          input.form-control(type='text', placeholder="Search for an item by its id", name="userInput")
       .form-row.mt-2
          .form-group
             select.form-control(name="quantity")
                option(value='1') Qty: 1
                option(value='2') Qty: 2
                option(value='3') Qty: 3
                option(value='4') Qty: 4
                option(value='5') Qty: 5
   .card-footer
        button.btn.btn-outline-secondary(type='submit')
           i.fas.fa-shopping-cart.mr-2
           | Add to my cart
```

Everything renders properly. I gave a "name" field to each form input I have and I try to grab that data from req.body.(name) in the app.js file. But when I run it and input data, nothing shows up in the console log.

Comment: have you tried `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: yes. It is literally a blank empty console log.

Comment: Have you seen network tab in browser? is post request actually hitting server?

Comment: It's not hitting the server. I don't see any "POST" in the network section of the console.

Comment: So your submit button is not actually submitting the form. As @vesse suggested bring button inside the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the `body-parser` but in your HTML. If you check from developer console you see no request being performed when the button is clicked, and that is because the button is not inside the form and thus does nothing.

Take the `.card-footer` out to have the button inside the form and you'll receive the request with parameters. The request will hang since `post` handler does not return anything, but you will see the parameter in the console.

Comment: Winner winner! This was the solution. Thank you so much. I knew it was simple.

Comment: @J.G.Sable I suggest you to make it habit of inspecting network tab when dealing with http requests, probably you would have figured it yourself.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm brand new to node/express so I'll incorporate that as a general practice. At least I won't make this exact same mistake again (but probably one substantially similar), hah.